# How to get records that match value or exist in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I am trying to figure out how to get all tasks in this case that two of the fields equal a certain value or they exist in the other table?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT TASKS.task_id, TASKS.task_title, TASKS.task_description, TASKS.task_assigned_name, TASKS.task_assigned_phone_number, TASKS.task_due_date_time, TASKS.task_category
FROM TASKS
WHERE TASKS.task_complete = 1 AND 
      (TASKS.task_creator_id = ? OR 
       TASKS.task_assigned_user_id = ? OR
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  WATCHERS.task_id
                     FROM WATCHERS
                     WHERE WATCHERS.task_id = TASK.task_id AND
                           WATCHERS.watcher_user_id = ?
                    )
     );
```

This is not returning anything even though I am expecting a result from my db.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an error in your syntax.  You have too many `WHERE`s:

```
   SELECT t.task_id, t.task_title, t.task_description, t.task_assigned_name, t.task_assigned_phone_number, t.task_due_date_time, t.task_category
    FROM TASKS t
    WHERE t.task_complete = 1 AND 
          (t.task_creator_id = ? OR 
           t.task_assigned_user_id = ? OR
           EXISTS (SELECT 1  -- the return value is immaterial
                   FROM WATCHERS w
                   WHERE w.task_id = t.task_id AND
                         w.watcher_user_id = ?
                  )
         );
```

The `WHERE` before `EXISTS` is not appropriate.

Your query should be returning an error.  Be sure to check for errors!

Comment: Ok yes I took off that where and made the changes but still not returning anything. It looks like the OR situations are being ignored?

Comment: @Lion789 . . . My guess is that nothing matches the parameters you are passing in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a join?

```
SELECT TASKS.task_id, 
       TASKS.task_title, 
       TASKS.task_description, 
       TASKS.task_assigned_name, 
       TASKS.task_assigned_phone_number, 
       TASKS.task_due_date_time, 
       TASKS.task_category
FROM TASKS
JOIN WATCHERS on WATCHERS.task_id = TASK.task_id
WHERE TASKS.task_complete = 1 AND 
  (TASKS.task_creator_id = ? OR 
   TASKS.task_assigned_user_id = ? OR
   WATCHERS.watcher_user_id = ?);
```

I'm not sure if that's the logic you are looking for.

besides the extra where in your query, looks like you may have an extra closed parenthesis.

Comment: Still returns an empty array when it clearly has task_creator_id and task_complete equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

This sql matches the result set you posted in your duplicate post that has sample data and result:

```
SELECT t.task_id, t.task_complete, t.task_creator_id, t.task_assigned_user_Id
FROM tasks t
WHERE t.task_complete = 1 AND
      (
      t.task_creator_id = 8
      OR t.task_assigned_user_id = 8
      OR EXISTS
          (
          SELECT w.task_id
          FROM watchers w
          WHERE w.task_id = t.task_id
          AND w.watcher_user_id = 8
          )
      )
```

Comment: How is this different from what I posted in the other post?

Comment: @Lion789 I do not how to get to the duplicate post so I cannot compare. But this query matches the result set you posted in the duplicate post. Before posting here I was posting there just when I was not allowed. So I followed the link and posted here.